# Where are the webform files in the D8 directory?

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to manually update the D8 webform module but cannot find any directory, folder, or file named webform.  Where are the webform module files located?

Comment: Wherever you installed them to, usually that would be docroot/modules/contrib

Comment: Perhaps you accidentally added it under `/core/modules`

Answer (score 0):

We can install the modules in (root/modules/contrib) as webform is contributed module.

But by default, all contrib modules are in (root/core/modules/webform.)